# Can I use the principal components of control variables in regression?

Tags: regression, pca, inference, controlling-for-a-variable

I am running a logistic regression and one of my control variables is categorical with $100$ categories. This leads to problems because some categories have $3$ data points, out of tens of thousands. The outcome is the success rate in $N$ trials, where each data point has a different $N$. Some categories have $0$ success rates, often because the $N$ is small and they have very few data points.

I have read about using principal components for prediction but that's not what I am trying to do. I need the variable as control - what happens if instead I use the principal components whose variance explained sums to a high number, like $95\%$? What if I use all of them?

Comment: Could you clarify what it means to "have 3 rows" and for a category to have an "instance of success"?

Comment: 3 rows means 3 data points per category (the data is in a table). My data is success rates in $N$ experiments, where $N$ is different for each data point. For some categories this success rate is $0$, often because of a very low number of trials $N$.

Comment: I think a better approach might be to use a random effects model instead.  The categories with many observations can naturally be estimated, while the sparse categories are pooled to the global mean of the data.